# Display an image in a word document with visualforce

Tags: visualforce, images, ms-word

I develop a visualforce page which generate a word document.

Unfortunately, the image in the word document is not displayed whereas it's ok in PDF and in visualforce page.

The document has the Externally Available Image "Externally Available Image" checked and I use that URL:

```
https://c.cs***.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=****&oid=***
```

This is my code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contract" extensions="VFC01_GenerateConsiderations" contentType="application/msword#filename.doc" showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false">

<html xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <head>
    </head>
  
    <body>
        <apex:image url="https://c.cs***.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=***&oid=***" />
    </body>
</html>
```

</apex:page>

What is wrong please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The response is I have to display an image with HTTP and not HTTPS.